# Как присвоить HTML класс блоку, находящемуся внутри PHP кода

Tags: php, html, css, классы

Как присвоить HTML класс блоку, находящемуся внутри PHP кода, чтобы на выводимом тексте срабатывала верстка?
Мне нужно не все блоки форматировать, а только выборочные, задать класс.

Связка, которая работает:

```
echo ("<div>Привет!</div>")

div {
    margin: 100px 0px 12px 100px;
}
```

Связка, которая не работает:

```
echo ("<div class="answer">Привет!</div>")

.answer {
    margin: 100px 0px 12px 100px;
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не экранируете кавычки. Попробуйте так:

```
echo ("<div class=\"answer\">Привет!</div>")
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает

Answer (score 0):

Интерпретатор вместо одной, видит две строки:
`<div class=`
и
`>Привет!</div>`, а между ними неизвестный ему оператор `answer`

Чтобы этого избежать можно комбинировать одинарные и двойные скобочки:

```
echo ("<div class='answer'>Привет!</div>")
```